# Scrollbar incorrectly appears underneath UICollectionView section header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

For some reason my scrollbar always appears underneath the collection view section header. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: This is an iOS 11 bug. The scroll bar is correctly positioned in iOS 10.

Answer (score 27):

I found a workaround. This issue is that the `zPosition` of the header view is being set by the collection view incorrectly. To fix this, we will always ensure that the `zPosition` is our desired value.

Create a `CALayer` subclass which prevents the `zPosition` from being anything other than 0.

```
class CustomLayer: CALayer {
    override var zPosition: CGFloat {
        get { return 0 }
        set {}
    }
}
```

Then set the layer class of your collection view header to this new subclass.

```
class MyHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {

    // your other custom code here

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        get { return CustomLayer.self }
    }

}
```

This is an iOS 11 bug, as this issue does not occur in iOS 10. Hopefully this works well enough until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this seems like a better solution than what I was doing. I basically just set the headerCell as a regular cell. but yours seem cleaner.

Comment: Great fix! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Its sad to see that this is still an issue in iOS 12

Answer (score 19):

Same concept, but here is a simpler workaround that doesn't require your `UICollectionReusableView` instances to use a subclass.

Conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` (if you don't already) and implement [willDisplaySupplementaryView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview) protocol method like so:

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    view.layer.zPosition = 0.0
}`

Tested in iOS 11.2.1.

Comment: @Nathan The bug only exists for iOS 11, so this code has no effect for iOS <=10. That being said, I have not tested this on iOS 11.0 or 11.1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my alternative which seems to work better on **iOS12** when subclassing `UICollectionReusableView`.

```
final class BasicCollectionSectionHeader: UICollectionReusableView {
    override var layer: CALayer {
        let layer = super.layer
        layer.zPosition = 0 // make the header appear below the collection view scroll bar
        return layer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a long-scrolling, async-loading collection, this alternative may offer slightly better performance.

```
class MyHeaderView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        layer.zPosition = 0
    }
}
```