# Edit row action displayed on top of table view section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios11

On iOS 11, the **cell edit actions or swipe actions**(available only for iOS 11) **are being displayed on top of the section headers**, if the table view style is set to plain (not grouped). This seems to be the default functionality and I'm wandering if this is a system bug or maybe my implementation is wrong.

I implemented a demo app, using a **default table view implementation** and the following functions for the headers and edit action rows:

**Title for Header**:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }
```

**Edit actions for row**:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let firstAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Action1", handler: {_,_ in })
        let secondAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Action2", handler: {_,_ in })
        return [firstAction, secondAction]
    }
```

**Trailing swipe action**(the new implementation only available on iOS 11):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action1 = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Action1", handler: {_,_,_ in })
        let action2 = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Action2", handler: {_,_,_ in })
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action1, action2])
    }
```

Here is a **screenshot** of how the edit actions are being displayed:
[image: Edit action overlapping section header]

**This only happens on iOS 11**. I have tried using **both methods** mentioned above alternatively, but I am getting the same results.

Do you have an idea of how I **might be able to fix this**? Is this an **iOS 11 system bug**?

Comment: looks like it happens on iOS 11.4 only. At least for me in that case.

Comment: I have tested this on other versions of iOS and it also happens on 11.2.2 for me, so I think it is a iOS 11 general issue

Comment: yeah just tested on iOS 11.3 and you are right @frozencure seems like iOS 11 only

Comment: @PratikMistry Do you think maybe we're doing something wrong and this might not be a system bug? I've looked for apps which run on iOS 11 and have plain tableviews with row actions but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: possible we are doing something wrong but so far it looks like a system bug to me. As same thing seems to be working fine in iOS 9 and iOS 10

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself :( working on iOS 9, 10 but not 11. Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: Did you find anything? I've got this problem on iOS 11.4

Comment: @codddeer123 See the answer below, it seems it triggers another bug but as soon as kd02 finds a solution you should be good to go.

Comment: Hey I am using this but this is not working for Section, it is only swipable for rows

Answer (score 3):

For anybody that comes across this issue I found a workaround by subclassing UITableViewHeaderFooterView class and then setting the [layer's zPostion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition) to 1 which will change the header's view ordering within the window's view rendering which solved it for me.

**Solution 1:**

```
open class HeaderFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    public override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.layer.zPosition = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternative workaround if you don't want to subclass the UITableViewHeaderFooterView class is to just override viewForHeaderInSection delegate method then set the view's zPosition before returning it.

**Solution 2:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "CustomHeader") as! CustomHeader

    headerView.title = "Header title"

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
         headerView.layer.zPosition = 1;
    }

    return headerView
}
```

Comment: I believe this solution will trigger another bug: the scroll bar will appear below the section header, because the scroll bar's zPosition is 0. You can see the `UICollectionView` counterpart of the bug [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46694144/1111252), where the solution is to set the header view's zPosition back to 0 (which would cause this question's bug to resurface).

Comment: Yes @peco you are correct, I'm able to replicate the bug with the scrollbar appearing behind the header. I'm going to try find at a fix for this. Thank you for letting me know.

Comment: Hey I am using this but this is not working for Section, it is only swipable for rows